# What's the difference between url_title and url_title_path?

Tags: variable, url-title

I keep running into issues, and apparently I just don't understand the difference between these two variables.  One set of pages works with url_title_path, and the other set will only act right with url_title.  There must be some difference I'm missing, but I don't know what it is.  any help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[url_title_path](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#id140) requires a `template_group/tempate` to be passed to it, so it can return a complete URL. It should be used when creating links. (It seems to be the same as [title_permalink](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#title-permalink), which is what I always use myself.)

e.g., `{url_title_path="news/entry"}` returns `http://mysite.com/news/entry/hello-world`

`url_title` is simply a variable which returns an entry's `url_title`, e.g., `hello_world`

Comment: This was [discussed](https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/139255/#686296) in 2009 and [confirmed](https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/220799/#1018421) by ExpressionEngine support in 2012.